# Text on image gallary html css javascript

Tags: gallery

I can't able to do like this
![Caption on Gallery][1]

What i want to do Click here on the below image
  [https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1SQD1vg0T6ibEFxS09nXzZTUFU/view?usp=sharing]

The link below that what i've done....
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1SQD1vg0T6iSU4xWTUzNVY0Q3c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you paste your code in here, please? I don't want to download your whole project just to view the code.

Comment: this is only Particular file ..i am new on stackoverflow so don't know how to put the code in there.. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for the thing which you want exactly as your example.

First of all remove .cd-intro classes from lines 134,138 and 143.

Now in line 125 replace the class with following.

```
.cd-intro
{
  background-color:black;
  color:#fff;
  font-family:"Lato",sans-serif;
  height:100%;
  opacity:0.8;
  overflow:visible;
  padding-top:90px; 
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center; 
  top:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

You will need to adjust `padding-top` as per the requirement.